# I want to write a command to putty.exe and after I close it I wannt it to continue

Tags: python-3

I used to write "python3.7 -m ftg" to rpi 4 model b without a screen, but it doesn't work now and I want to do it with pc.

I want to write "python3.7 -m ftg" in putty than I want to close it (command will be still working).

Comment: `nohup python3.7 -m ftg &` will leave it running when you log off.

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- What is the usage of `python3.7 -m ftg`?

Comment: what is `it`? .... you use the word multiple times, so your question is unclear as a result

Comment: I see, it is working now (your comment in an answer is deleted). Please accept the answer from *@Andyroo* or explain with your own answer, how do you solve the problem. Then after two days accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

The first basic way would be to add `</dev/null &>/dev/null &` to the end of the line.  This disconnects the job but you loose any output from the program:

```
python3.7 -m ftg </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

You could pipe the output to a file if you needed the data:

```
python3.7 -m ftg </dev/null &>/home/pi/output.log &
```

A better solution though is to use the [nohup](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm) program as this lets you output directly to the home directory.

```
nohup python3.7 -m ftg output.log &
```

This will then let you reconnect to the Pi and bring the program back into the foreground with the `fg` command.

An alternative way would be to use the `screen` or `tmux` programs.  This let you disconnect from the terminal and reconnect again.  Both of these can split a terminal session into multiple windows and control each as a separate job.

Comment: no no you understood wrong, I mean: I want to enter the code than it will continue even I close putty

Comment: @MehmetKan Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/110978/edit) your question and elaborate it, so it is clearer.